# Redirect all (non-rejected) spam to a special mailbox in sa-exim

Tags: spam, redirect, exim, sa-exim

I'd like to redirect all spams (that weren't rejected outright) to mailbox of local user `spam` (i.e. deliver mail to `spam` user rather than to original local recipient).

I'm using `sa-exim` (exim 4 + spamassasin 3.2) on Debian (it's got its own `exim4.conf.template` convoluted config).

I've tried adding the following router (before exim's `real_local`):

```
 spams:
  debug_print = "R: spams $local_part@$domain"
  driver = redirect
  condition = ${if def:h_X-Spam-Flag {1}{0}}
  allow_fail
  allow_defer
  check_local_user
  domains = +local_domains
  data = spam@localhost
```

but it doesn't seem to be triggered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that the new router is being used by exim

```
grep spams /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

Then do some debugging, something like:

```
cat message-with-header.txt | exim -bm -t -d+route
```

You should see it run through each router, so check if it runs yours and hopefully tell you why its not working (condition failed, earlier router already took the message, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Using the following condition works fine for me:

```
  condition = "${if def:h_X-Spam-Flag: {yes}{no}}"
```